# Convert MS Access query to SQL Server query

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access

Here is the part of code that is been used in MS Access query. What should I use instead for SQL Server query? The format of date is same as `GETDATE()`.

```
  ((IIf([DATE]-Int([DATE])>0,'N',Null)) Is Null));
```

I tried using `CASE` and it's not working.

Comment: What is this trying to find, records that are at midnight?

Comment: yes kind of and looking for NULL value in there

Answer (score 1):

If I get this correctly, you're testing if the timepart of the date is midnight.

You can do that in the following way:

```
Cast([DATE] AS Time) = '00:00:00'
```

Your Access code, by the way, can be minimized to:

```
[DATE]-Int([DATE])=0
```

Comment: what if its [DATE]-Int([DATE])>0 in access ?  how do you convert that?

Comment: Then you can change `=` to `<>`